# Integrity constraint violation while making query multiple tables in Yii2

Tags: sql, yii2

I have sql scheme like this [image]
And i want to make query to provide data to view.

```
public function frontendProvider()
{

    $query = new Query;
    $query  ->select('*')  
            ->from('strategy')
            ->join('LEFT JOIN', 
                'risk_colors',
                'risk_colors.id = risk_colors_id'
            )
            ->join('LEFT JOIN',
                'strategyoptions',
                'strategyoptions.strategy_id = id'
            );        
    $provider = new ArrayDataProvider([
        'allModels' => $query->createCommand()->queryAll(),
        'sort' => [
            'defaultOrder' => [
                'risk_colors_id' => SORT_DESC, 

            ],
            'attributes' => [
                'strategy_title', 
                'strategy_description', 
                'strategy_current_money',
                'color_number',
                'risk_colors_id',
                'options_value',
            ],
        ],
    ]); 

    return $provider;

}
```

After i refresh index page i got this error 
[image]

I am newbie, but it seems like i have problem this relation of my tables, i not sure. What should i do to makes things works right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're joinig two tables with the same column name (`id`), you need to prefix column name by table name, to specify which one should be used:

```
$query  ->select('*')  
        ->from('strategy')
        ->join('LEFT JOIN', 
            'risk_colors',
            'risk_colors.id = risk_colors_id'
        )
        ->join('LEFT JOIN',
            'strategyoptions',
            'strategyoptions.strategy_id = strategy.id' // <- here
        );
```